# WebTestClient cannot post body to MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-test, spring-restcontroller, spring-webclient

The RestTemplate javadoc recommends migrating to WebClient, even for traditional (non-reactive) applications. So it's logical that I would also like to use WebTestClient in my controller tests, to use a consistent API.

This works fine for GET requests for example. But when I POST with a body, the body data does not arrive at the controller. Why not?

I can test my controllers like this:

```
WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(TokenController()).build

webTestClient.post().uri("/post2")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .bodyValue("grant_type=authorization_code")
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk()
```

The controller code:

```
@PostMapping(
    path = ["/post2"],
    consumes = [APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE],
    produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
ResponseEntity<Any> post2(@RequestParam(GRANT_TYPE) String grantType) {
    System.out.println(grantType)
    return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"a\": 33}")
}
```

In this example, grantType is null. If I start the application and send a standard HTTP request, then grantType contains the value "authorization_code" as expected.

(I manually translated the code from Kotlin to Java for this question, there may be syntax errors)

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually parsing the body at all in your controller, you are only looking for a URL parameter.

`@RequestParam("grant_type")` will map a **parameter** like /someUrl?grant_type=something

But you are sending the data in the body of the request, so you should use

`@RequestBody String grantType` in your controller instead. Note that the input will be the whole String "grant_type=authorization_code".

Comment: I guess you mean `@RequestBody`, not `@ResponseBody`

Comment: You're absolutely right Justin, edited the reply!